# I cant locate the exe file in the bz2 I have downloaded

Tags: plugins, download, extract, exe, bz2

Essentially I need to download a bz2 file, save it, and run the exe file within a program I am using (pano2vr). Issue is - I can't find the exe file in the bz2 download.

Here are the instructions:
https://ggnome.com/doc/glossary_ffmpeg/

Here is the file I've downloaded and extracted (using PeaZip):
https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows

I can't find the exe file (that the instructions refer to) anywhere! Help!

Answer (score 0):

What you have downloaded is the source code, which, as the name implies, contains code but not an executable. If you wish to download an executable and do not wish to compile from source, you can follow one of the links under the Windows EXE files section of the website you linked.

For instance, https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-full.zip